# Open chart_php comand

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! У меня проблема с open chart. Там в установки написано, что надо сделать upload некоторые папки и файлы. Так вот, когда я открываю HTML страницу, делаю обзор, выбираю файл и нажимаю отправить у меня выходит сам PHP код страницы, а не его команды типа-имя документа или его размер.

Answer (score 1):

Значит, у вас либо файл скрипта имеет окончание (расширение) не php, либо в нем команды пхп обрамляются `<?` вместо `<?php`, либо у вас просто нет пхп на сервере.

Comment: Нет, точно не это, так как это не редкая проблема и на форумах посстоянно говорят про php.ini, но покрутил уже все настройки и перезапускал сервер по 100 раз, но всё та же проблема.

Comment: То, что говорят на форумах про пхп ини, это обычно и есть проблема обрамления кода. Посмотрите в вашем скрипте, какое обромление полное (знак меньше знак вопроса и слово php) или короткое (знак меньше и знак вопроса). Отсюда обычно у таких проблем ноги и растут. Посмотрите параметр `short_open_tag`  в пхп и поставьте его `short_open_tag` = On